# In Python 3, how do I write non-Latin characters from an arbitrary web request to file?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to request an arbitrary HTML page via request.urlopen, and write the result to a file. This works for most English cases. However, if the source contains any non-Latin characters, the write fails (see below). I would prefer to write the special characters, but would settle for replacing them with nothing or `?`

```
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.example.com").read()
file = open("example.html", "w")
file.write(html.decode("utf-8")) # works
file.close()

html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enheduanna").read()
file = open("enheduanna.html", "w")
file.write(html.decode("utf-8")) # fails
file.close()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    file.write(html.decode("utf-8")) # fails
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 26041-26
045: character maps to <undefined>
```

I get the same error if I use `requests.get` or `requests.post`, and if I try `decode("utf-8","replace")` or not decoding.

Comment: fwiw this is on Windows

Comment: @KarolS that led me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary web request, it might be easiest to blindly retain the original encoding. In this case, write the bytes rather than encoding/decoding to string:

```
file = open("enheduanna.html", "bw")
...
file.write(html)
```

(Thanks to Karol S for suggesting writing without decoding.)

Comment: The response object *should* have the charset in the headers. I would try that and transcode to UTF-8. But fall back on writing binary for a decode error. The default file encoding is the Windows codepage (1252), so override this. `charset = response.headers.get_content_charset(failobj='latin-1'); html = response.read().decode(charset)`; `file = open('enheduanna.html', 'w', encoding=charset); file.write(html)`